# How to get rid of these co-related sub queries from select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, correlated-subquery

Here I am dealing with only one table, It has an attribute called CmpltStscd where for each value I need a different column in the output as an aggregate function.

Is there a way to get rid of these subqueries ?

Trying a lot

```
Select 
      Mg.RsrcId
    , Count(Mg.ActID) Num_of_Goals
    , (SELECT COUNT(MC.ActID) FROM TM.MatrixGoal MC where MC.CmpltStsCd = 2 AND MG.RsrcID = MC.RsrcID AND MC.ActiveFlg = 1 AND MC.DelFlg = 0 AND MC.CorporateGoalFlg <> 1 AND MC.StsCd in (3,4)) as Complete
    , (SELECT COUNT(MI.ActID) FROM TM.MatrixGoal MI where MI.CmpltStsCd = 4 AND MG.RsrcID = MI.RsrcID AND MI.ActiveFlg = 1 AND MI.DelFlg = 0 AND MI.CorporateGoalFlg <> 1 AND MI.StsCd in (3,4)) as Issues
    , (SELECT COUNT(MO.ActID) FROM TM.MatrixGoal MO where MO.CmpltStsCd = 1 AND MG.RsrcID = MO.RsrcID AND MO.ActiveFlg = 1 AND MO.DelFlg = 0 AND MO.CorporateGoalFlg <> 1 AND MO.StsCd in (3,4)) as OnTrack
From 
TM.MatrixGoal AS Mg

Where MG.ActiveFlg = 1
            AND MG.DelFlg = 0
            AND MG.CorporateGoalFlg <> 1
            AND MG.StsCd in (3,4)
Group By RsrcId
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a pivot/cross tab query

```
SELECT Mg.RsrcId,
       COUNT(Mg.ActID) Num_of_Goals,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN CmpltStsCd = 2 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END)        AS Complete,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN CmpltStsCd = 4 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END)        AS Issues,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN CmpltStsCd = 1 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END)        AS OnTrack
FROM   TM.MatrixGoal AS Mg
WHERE  MG.ActiveFlg = 1
       AND MG.DelFlg = 0
       AND MG.CorporateGoalFlg <> 1
       AND MG.StsCd IN ( 3, 4 )
GROUP  BY RsrcId
```

Comment: That worked like charm!
Now i need to add one more column to the query, but the attribute I am dealing with has Empty space for few  records, NULL for few , and a VARCHARid for few records. How do I add it as a column using the same logic ?

Eg: 

If prntactid != "" then aligned
Else Unligned.

I need something like :
SUM(CASE
         WHEN prntactid != "" THEN 1
        ELSE 0
END)  AS ALIGNED

But its throwing error as it doesnt accept spaces or "" or [].
Any work around ?

Comment: `''` denotes an empty string in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use conditional aggregation:

```
Select Mg.RsrcId, Count(Mg.ActID) Num_of_Goals,
       SUM(CASE WHEN mg.CmpltStsCd = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Complete,
       SUM(CASE WHEN mg.CmpltStsCd = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Issues
       SUM(CASE WHEN mg.CmpltStsCd = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as OnTrack
From TM.MatrixGoal Mg
Where MG.ActiveFlg = 1 AND MG.DelFlg = 0 AND MG.CorporateGoalFlg <> 1 AND 
     MG.StsCd in (3,4)
Group By RsrcId;
```